# On the Mac, how can I get saved Terminal window groups (or other saved window groups) to work across multiple Spaces?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, osx-spaces

I've got a nice startup script on my computer that opens up the various applications I need to get to work, making good use of Terminal's "Windows"->"Save Windows as Group"/"Open Window Group" option. The only problem with this is that if I have windows spread across multiple spaces, "Save Windows as Group" will notice all of them and save their location, but will NOT restore them to the appropriate Space next time I open the program (with that group) - instead, it will open them all in the current space.

Perhaps it's just a limitation of the application, but if there's a way to do this solutions are appreciated.

Comment: If it's important to you for Window Groups to be able to remember the Space of each window, please file an enhancement bug report: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of the operating system. There is no support for applications to place windows in a specific space. However, on Mac OS X Lion you can use Resume. If you quit Terminal with windows still open, the next time you open it all your windows will be restored in the appropriate spaces (including Full Screen windows).